# "ERROR: timestamp out of range" converting epoch stored as bigint to a timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, postgresql-10, type-conversion

I'm getting `ERROR:  timestamp out of range: "1.52701e+15"` when trying to convert an epoch stored as a bigint into a timestamp (value is taken from a real database table):

```
select to_timestamp(1527012834506374);
ERROR:  timestamp out of range: "1.52701e+15"
```

Other approaches to conversion don't work either:

```
select 1527012834506374::abstime::timestamp;
ERROR:  cannot cast type bigint to abstime

select 1527012834506374::integer::abstime::timestamp;
ERROR:  integer out of range
```

It's a valid epoch; https://www.epochconverter.com/ tells me 1527012834506374 is equivalent to 2018-05-22 06:13:54.506 UTC

How can I do the conversion using SQL in Postgres?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I paste the value `1527012834506374` into  https://www.epochconverter.com/ I see the warning:

> *Assuming that this timestamp is in microseconds (1/1,000,000 second):*

Postgres' `to_timestamp()` assumes an epoch with seconds, not microseconds, so you need to use:

```
select to_timestamp(1527012834506374 / 1000000.0)
```

Comment: Agreed, by definition the Unix epoch is a number of seconds in a 32 bits signed integer, hence the maximum value possible is 2 147 483 647, anything higher than that is something else, like the epoch padded with 3 digits of milliseconds or 6 digits of microseconds.

Comment: Make that `to_timestamp(1527012834506374 / 1000000.0)` to avoid integer division truncating fractional digits.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek And I was wondering why the numbers I had looked so big. They come from ejabberd's archive table. Spot the DBA here that never stores dates and times as numbers :-)